# Can't View Full Page Source in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium

I'm trying to run some test inputs on a website backdoor using Selenium.

When I view the source HTML after manually navigating to the site via Firefox/Chrome/IE I can see the full page source.

However, when the Selenium driver launches the site it can't intereact with any of the items on the page and the source HTML returned is only the following line:

```
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8' /><style type='text/css'>BODY { Margin:0;background: #8ebad6; }</style><iframe src="/Admin/Log_in.aspx" width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="0" align="center"></iframe>
```

This is the case no matter which web driver I use.

Why does the page source present itself like this and how can I get around this so that Selenium is able to interact with the page

Answer (score 3):

I needed to switch to the iframe in order to access the HTML encapsulated within it. For the HTML above I used the following Java code to switch the Selenium driver to the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```